# Commerce coupon redemption form into block

Tags: 8, commerce

How to load commerce_coupon_redemption_form programmatically into custom block? I have to show the coupon form into a block in cart page.

i try this into my custom block plugin:

```
public function build() {
      return array(
        '#theme' => 'mycustom_block_template',
        '#content' => array('tot' => 100),
        '#form' => [
              '#type' => 'commerce_coupon_redemption_form',
              '#title' => t('Coupon code'),
              '#description' => t('Enter your coupon code to redeem a promotion.'),
              '#order_id' => 3,
              '#cardinality' => 1,
              '#element_ajax' => [
                  ['redemee-block', 'ajaxRefreshSummary'],
              ],
         ],
         '#cache' => ['max-age' => 0]
      );
}
```

where into my MYMODULE.module i have:

```
function MYMODULE_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
    return [
        'mycustom_block_template' => [
            'variables' => [
                'content' => NULL,
                'form' => NULL
            ],
            'render element' => 'form'
        ],
    ];
}
```

and my template is

```
<div>{{ content.tot }}</div>

<div>{{ form }}</div>
```

i can see the values into content variables but the form is never show. 
where is my fault?
thanks

Comment: It’s always a good idea to read the docs for a hook before implementing it ;) _Each information array must contain either a 'variables' element (for using a #theme element) or a 'render element' element (for render elements), but not both._

Comment: Thanks Clive, i try _variables_ and also only _render element_ but the form is never shown. i have to show the form into my template with other variables. when i use only _variables_ i have only this `<div title="" data-toggle="tooltip" class="form-group" data-original-title="Enter your coupon code to redeem a promotion."></div>` in my html.